# VBA-excel loop textbox

Tags: excel, vba, loops, for-loop

I'm still learning the ropes of using vba. I have userform consisting of textboxEs that I want to display based on combobox and listbox selection. There is data being read from a sheet.

Essentially, I'm trying to do a loop within a loop but there seems to be a problem after the first loop.

I'm going to post a picture to demonstrate the problem:

Userform

[image]

As you can see from the texboxes, the loop won't seem to work. It seems to be stuck. The loop code for entering the textboxes work, but the value inside the textboxes are wrong.

```
'antall butikker
For b = 1 To antall_rader
    If Ark1.Cells(b, "L").Value = Me.cmbDistributoor.Value And Ark1.Cells(b, "O").Value = lstRuteTur.Value Then
        Me.txtAntallButikk.Value = Ark1.Cells(b, "M").Value
    End If
Next b

For a = 1 To Me.txtAntallButikk.Value
    For C = 1 To antall_rader
        If Not Ark1.Cells(C, "L").Value = Me.cmbDistributoor.Value And Ark1.Cells(C, "O").Value = lstRuteTur.Value Then
        Else

            If Me("Textbox" & a).Value = "" Then
                Me("Textbox" & a).Value = Ark1.Cells(C, "I").Value
            End If
        End If
    Next C
Next a
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It's hard to follow what exactly your code is meant to be doing - but I notice you use `If Not` after the inner loop. You also have an `And` operator on that line, do you perhaps want to also use `Not` here? (e.g. `If Not [...] And Not [...] Then`)

Comment: Hi, Macro Man. Im trying to experiment different codes, i dont know if that is a good use of using "if not". The cmbDistributoor.Value is value from combobox and lstRuteTur.Value is value from listbox. When They are selected, you usually get about 4-5 values in the sheet. I want to be able to populate the textboxes after those 2 selections are being made.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Got it to work. I created 2 listboxes filling out the data that i used as condition, and from there it presented the same amount of n as the amount in textboxes. Then i used i =to (something) to display the data.

Comment: good work dude, well done for sticking at it and getting there (y)